# Is it possible to have one formula that can scrape any given url for universal properties?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, url

As I am new to the world of scraping, I need some help. I am creating an app called "Job Pocket" that will help with saving jobs and recommending jobs. It has two sections: A **"Recommended"** section and a **"My List"** section.

Within the **"Recommended"** section I have successfully scraped the RSS feed from Craigslist and appended the main information that I wanted to the DOM as a list: (Url, Title, description, and date). The title links back to the actual job posting on Craigslist. Right now I am scraping the RSS feed from craigslist with jQuery and Javascript. I will have to refactor this later to an AngularJS way.

What I am having a ***difficult time*** with is the **"My List"** section. This section allows users to copy an url to a job posting from any site and add it to the "My List" section for saving.

**I would like to be able to scrape any given url for the main tags such as: title, first image and first 200-500 characters of the body.**

I feel that these properties should be apart of most if not all urls. Is it possible to make a single or very few functions that will be able to do this?

I would like to see a solution either by using Javascript with AngularJS or jQuery.

Here is a link to my repo on Github if you need it =  [Github Repo](https://github.com/omaracrystal/Job_Pocket_V2)

Comment: It looks like you are already using Cheerio.  You can definitely use Cheerio to parse those elements out on the server side and serve them up to the client.  I don't think you'd be able to do the parsing on the client, because of cross origin restrictions (assuming this is a web app).

Comment: I am currently using jQuery on the client side to get the RSS feed. I tried to use cheerio on the server side along with some bots but was unsuccessful.   So you are saying that if I receive a url from the client via input form... I cannot scrape that url without first passing it to the server?